# Awk formatting issue for XML

Tags: awk, xml

There is an issue with the output XML format due to Record separator (RS = "\n \n"). The group of data is separated by an empty line. Any suggestion would be very much helpful to obtain the desired output.

Following is my input which is present in input.txt

`Alex`
`Marks300`
`SubjectScience`

`Robin`
`Marks200`
`SubjectChemistry`

I am trying to get an output as below:

```
<candidate>
<name>Alex</name>
<marks>Marks300</marks>
<subject>SubjectScience</subject>
</candidate>

<candidate>
<name>Robin</name>
<marks>Marks200</marks>
<subject>SubjectChemistry</subject>
</candidate>
```

I am trying to use the following code but it is not working:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = "\\n";RS = "\\n\\n";
print " "}
{ print "<candidate>" }
{ print "<name>"$1"</name>" }
{ print "<marks>"$2"</marks>" }
{ print "<subject>"$3"</subject>" }
{ print "</candidate>" }
{print " " }' input.txt > candiatefinaloutput.xml
```

With the above code, getting an output as below:

`<candidate>`
`<name>alex<\name>`
`<marks><\marks>`
`<subject><\subject>`

`<name>Marks300<\name>`
`<marks><\marks>`
`<subject><\subject>`

`<name>SubjectScience<\name>`
`<marks><\marks>`
`<subject><\subject>`

`<name>Robin<\name>`
`<marks><\marks>`
`<subject><\subject>`

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = "\n";RS = "\n\n";
print " "}
{ print "<candidate>" }
{ print "<name>"$1"</name>" }
{ print "<marks>"$2"</marks>" }
{ print "<subject>"$3"</subject>" }
{ print "</candidate>" }
{print " " }' input.txt > candiatefinaloutput.xml
```

And there is what i get:

```
[romeo.romeo-PC] ➤ cat 3
Alex
Marks300
SubjectScience

Robin
Marks200
SubjectChemistry
                                                                                                                               ✔
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[2015-05-07 09:00.04]  ~/tmp
[romeo.romeo-PC] ➤ awk 'BEGIN{FS = "\n";RS = "\n\n";
print " "}
{ print "<candidate>" }
{ print "<name>"$1"</name>" }
{ print "<marks>"$2"</marks>" }
{ print "<subject>"$3"</subject>" }
{ print "</candidate>" }
{print " " }' 3

<candidate>
<name>Alex</name>
<marks>Marks300</marks>
<subject>SubjectScience</subject>
</candidate>

<candidate>
<name>Robin</name>
<marks>Marks200</marks>
<subject>SubjectChemistry </subject>
</candidate>
```

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand the difference between my code and what you have provided. Both look alike. Is there a difference which I am missing.

Comment: Yes, for name I use 1st token, for marks second ($2) (you use again first) and for subject I use 3th (you again 1st token) ($3)

Comment: My mistake. I intended to write the token $2 $3. I have now edited my question. I have also provided the output I am currently getting with the given code.

Comment: I see. I edit my answer, please test it. And try gnu awk: gawk (if UNIX system)

Comment: Thanks. I am not on a UNIX system. I have now narrowed down my issue to the record separator. For some reason, it is not taking //n//n

Comment: IMHO there is no problem with RS, check my edited answer

Comment: P.S. Check please if your input file is in UNIX (not DOS) format. This can be also the problem

Comment: I verified my input file is in the UNIX format. I tried a different delimiter instead of \n\n to ; by inserting ; in between groups of data. Now. only the first set in XML looks good. Remaining $1, $2, $3 are getting shifted to one step forward. Meaning. The second erroneous block look like <name></name> <marks>alex> <subject>Marks200>.

Comment: Check your source file, IMHO the problem is there. I show you above all work fine with correctly formatted file. You can use od program to see the ascii and hex presentation of content of the file

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to solve my issue by putting "RS = "";

Comment: Not sure if there is a way I can thank in the system. I do not see one.

Comment: If you want to mark some answer as helpful you can use arrows in left. Up for good answer, down for bad answer. You should have also icon for marking particular answer as definitive answer to your question

Comment: Sure. I was able to mark answer as useful. But it did not allow me to do an up arrow since I do not have the required reputation count as yet.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not that you are missing the closing single quote for awk - hopefully typo! Also remember you can just print "\n" instead of lots of separate print commands (or even use a semicolon to separate them).

Comment: No. the quote was missed in my question but it is present in my actual code. I added it here as well now. Thanks for your tip on the /n :)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use awk for XML parsing. This is a bad idea, because XML supports things like line feeding, indentation, line wrapping on attributes and unary tags - all of which means that semantically identical XML breaks when you use a line/field/regex oriented approach.

So I would strongly suggest using an XML tool to build your XML - and as an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' );
$twig->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('root') );

open( my $input, "<", "input.txt" ) or die $!;

local $/ = "\n\n";

while (<$input>) {
    my ( $name, $marks, $subject ) = (m/(\w+)\nMarks(\d+)\nSubject(\w+)/s);
    my $candidate = $twig->root->insert_new_elt( 'last_child', 'candidate' );
    $candidate->insert_new_elt( 'last_child', 'name',    $name );
    $candidate->insert_new_elt( 'last_child', 'marks',   $marks );
    $candidate->insert_new_elt( 'last_child', 'subject', $subject );
}
close($input);
$twig->print;
```

As a result, you can arbitrarily set your output format to something that's neatest for display your content. In the interests of generating 'proper' valid XML, you probably also want to include:

```
$twig -> set_xml_version('1.0');
$twig -> set_encoding('utf-8');
```